# Monitor SQL TCP traffic on the client

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, tcpip

I have a Windows 7 client that has a data driven application that connects to our SQL Server 2008 R2.
How can I view all the traffic between this software and the DB?
I would mainly like to see queries and responses.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest would be to run a server-side or client-side trace using [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

Another option might be to use a protocol analyzer, such as WireShark, or one of the many mentioned in this search result: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tcp+protocol+analyzer&t=ffsb

Comment: +1 for the duckduckgo - I've been meaning to change over for a while. Basically, I think at this point Google knows more about me than my girlfriend and mother combined!

Comment: undoubtedly!  Use the Duck, Luke!